# Why does the squares get disappear when the view get scaled?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code runs without throwing any errors.
The code has two views, the `content` view shows the child view `Squares`.
It creates new black squares when the button is clicked, then when you click on them the view gets scaled (magnified).
The issue is the black squares disappear when scaling.

I tried it with only one view, then it scales with the squares, but once I embed the code as a seperate view, then the squares gets disappear.

I want the parent view to scale with all the child views embedded in it without disappearing.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum ColumnTypes {
   case Square, Circular
}

final class ColumnsArrayObservedMain: ObservableObject {
    @Published var columnsArray : [ColumnsModelMain] = []
    @Published var randomPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}

struct ColumnsModelMain: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()  
    @State var columnWidth: Int
    @State var columnLength: Int
    @State var columnHeight: Int
    @State var columnType: ColumnTypes
    @State var columnPosition: CGPoint
    
 }

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var scaleby = 2.0
    @State var scalingEnabled = true;
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center) {
                        
Squares()
                
        }
        .scaleEffect(scaleby)
                     .onTapGesture {
                         if scalingEnabled == true {
                             withAnimation {scaleby *= 2}
                         }
                     }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}

struct Squares: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal = ColumnsArrayObservedMain()
    @State private var columnPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    @State private var recColour: Color = .black
    @State private var dragAmount: CGPoint?
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal.columnsArray, id: \.id) { column in
                    
                    
                    Rectangle ()
                        .fill (Color.black)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .position(column.columnPosition)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            
            
            
            Button ("Append last") {
                
                columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal.columnsArray.append(ColumnsModelMain( columnWidth: 10, columnLength: 100, columnHeight: 10, columnType: ColumnTypes.Square, columnPosition: columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal.randomPosition))
                
                columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal.randomPosition = CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 1...400), y: CGFloat.random(in: 1...400))
               
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `@State` only belongs inside SwiftUI views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Squares` use:

```
@StateObject private var columnsArrayObservedObjectLocal = ColumnsArrayObservedMain()
```

instead of  `@ObservedObject private ...`.

They will not disappear, because using `@StateObject`, from the docs:
`SwiftUI creates a new instance of the model object only once during the lifetime of the container that declares the state object.`, as opposed to be re-created every time the view changes.